# Angular JS issue with nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array on object like this:

```
$scope.techniques = [
 {
  programmes : 'genie' , 
  documents :[
    {
     menuTag: 'Moments et Centroïdes',
     titre: "Moments et Centroïdes",
     contenu: "moment.html"
    }]
},
{
  programmes : 'test' , 
  documents :[
    {
     menuTag: 'test de test',
     titre: "test",
     contenu: "test.html"
    }]
}
];
```

I am trying to build my menu with nested ng-repeat and exemple found on stackoverflow are not working. Cant figure ou why.

Here is my html;

```
<button ng-repeat="tech in techniques" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{tech.programmes}}
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

   <ul  class="dropdown-menu">
          <li ng-repeat="doc in tech.documents"><a href="../{{doc.contenu}}" ng-cloak>{{doc.menuTag}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can see the programmes but I cant see the documents inside programmes.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing <li> ? you would probably want to have ul outside and repeat the li

Comment: Oh... and you need to have the doc repeat inside the tech repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're trying to access "tech" outside of the first ng-repeat-scope. So it's not beeing nested.

```
<div ng-repeat="tech in techniques">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
       {{tech.programmes}}
       <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul ng-repeat="doc in tech.documents" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="../{{doc.contenu}}" ng-cloak>{{doc.menuTag}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not under the iteration of $scope.techniques.

```
<button ng-repeat="tech in techniques" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{tech.programmes}}
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<!-- tech does not existe anymore-->
<ul ng-repeat="doc in tech.documents" class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="../{{doc.contenu}}" ng-cloak>{{doc.menuTag}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two ng-repeats are not actually nested. In order to nest two ng-repeats, the second ng-repeat should be within the range of the first ng-repeat. You cannot access the 'tech' outside the button element. To make it work, wrap both button and ul inside a div, and define the first ng-repeat on the div instead of button.